# Javascript injection to class

Tags: javascript, csv, file-upload

I'm working with a website that accepts a csv file and uploads the contents into inventory. I would like to be able to have a javascript command that would allow me to automatically set the file input to specific file (always in C:\temp\file.csv). Here is the html I'm looking at

```
<input type="file" accept=".csv" ng-model="fileData" id="55" name="csvSerialsFiles" ngf-select="onFileSelect($files)" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-touched ng-untouched" __ngf_gen__="true">
```

Is it possible to select the file without having the user pick the file? I thought I could use something like this...

```
document.GetElementsByName('csvSerialsFiles')[0].value = 'C:\temp\file.csv'
```

but that doesn't end up doing anything, because I think its reading the file path as just a generic string. Is there any way to inject the file into the website? The users can still hit a 'Select File' and choose the correct file, but it would be a lot easier if I can make it avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible for security reasons. You want to use the innocuous file 'C:\temp\file.csv', but if this were possible, someone else could specify '/etc/passwd' or 'C:\important\windows\file'. As the script could then submit the form containing the file input, this would allow someone to serve a page that automatically uploads any file that the author knows (or can guess) the path of.